# Как написать php cronjob скрипт с определенными условиями

Tags: php

Есть скрипт на PHP, который должен брать данные из АПИ одного сервиса и по циклу импортировать их в базу данных WordPress (woocommerce продукты). Продуктов много. Вообще это должен быть cronjob скрипт, который не только импортирует, но и сверяет и обновляет данные в магазине.

Проблема в том, что по мере выполнения скрипта, память не очищается и по достижению предела, скрипт молча выключается.

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
        $this->import($product);
}
```

Моя идея в том, чтобы разбить программу на части. Например при `$currentMemory > 100MB` останавливать скрипт, записывать массив данных `$products` и номер итерации в файл и запускать скрипт с параметрами снова, чтобы он продолжил импорт с той итерации, где закончился предыдущий скрипт.

Как тогда, в таком случае, запустить следующий скрипт? И как его не запускать лишний раз, в случае, когда импорт завершился?

Может быть есть идея получше?

Answer (score 1):

в php скрипт можно передавать аргументы из cli:
php /path/to/project/index.php 0 100

внутри скрипта аргументы будут доступны через переменную $argv